# Keyboard shortcut to switch screens on split view

Tags: macos, screen

I want to know if there is any keyboard shortcut to switch between splits screen in all new El Capitan.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another *partial* solution. If you split your screen between two windows of the same program, e.g. Safari, then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) will toggle between the two.

Caveats and Special Cases:

- If for some reason this does not work, you probably don't have this shortcut enabled. The answer at https://superuser.com/a/187072 explains how to do this.
- This was tested on High Sierra, but should work just the same on El Capitan, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

I really hope someone has a better answer, but if not, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works if the two last apps you've touched are the two apps being splitscreened.

Comment: Cmd+tab won't work. That lists all the running apps. Switching turns hard with that.

Comment: @androidplusios.design It lists all the running apps if you hold it down. If you press it and quickly release it, it just switches between the two most recent apps.

Comment: And may be the recent apps aren't on same split screen.

Comment: I know. That's why I said "if the two last apps you've touched are the two apps being splitscreened."

Comment: I don't have a designated keyboard shortcut for switching between the two apps on my screen. I'm just telling you my workaround so you can use it while I join you in waiting for someone with a better answer to show up.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard

Click the `^f4` and type your prefered shortcut. (I set mine to `control tab`)

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me unfortunately.

Comment: works for me with option tab, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible**

For Google Chrome for macOS users:

Hit <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to go the right screen.

Hit <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to go to the left screen.